# Selenium looses session when document.location is called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, session, webdriver

I log in a website using the Chrome webdriver with Selenium.
When I make it click on a link whose href is the Javascript function "document.location", it apparently looses the session since it gets redirected to the login page.

```
<a href="javascript:document.location='/'+'some-location'+'/'">A link</a>
```

It seems to me that it's likely not a bug but an expected behavior without some specific intervention on my part, but I can't find what to do to prevent that.

EDIT:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

import time
import random

loginurl = 'https://www.website.com/myads/'

accounts = [
["login1", "pass1"],
["login2", "pass2"]
]


print("Generating the browser.")

user_agent = UserAgent().random
print("Using user agent : " + user_agent)

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") 
chrome_options.add_argument("--nogui")
chrome_options.add_argument("--nosandbox") 
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

i = 0


while i < len(accounts):
    print("Getting to the login page.")
    browser.get(loginurl)

    print("Waiting...")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 4))

    print("Filling login form.")

    print("Email : " + accounts[i][0])
    email_input = browser.find_element_by_id("email")
    email_input.send_keys(accounts[i][0])

    print("Waiting...")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 4))

    print("Password : " + accounts[i][1])
    password_input = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
    password_input.send_keys(accounts[i][1])

    print("Waiting...")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 4))

    print("Loggin in.")
    submit = browser.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
    cookies = browser.manage().get_cookies()

    print("Waiting...")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 4))

    print("Getting to my ads.")
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='myads']").click()

    # ...
```

Comment: I only tested in command line, I print the output of the page and I recognize the login page. I've just learned I could command an actual chrome page from the Python cli. I'm testing.

Comment: It's really a redirection in the same window, in the same tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the link in the document I used a pattern that actually matched several links, and several of them had the purpose of logging out.

Getting some fresh air from time to time is the key.